How to calculate the functional derivative of a product?
Let $\omega_{J}^{I}=\omega^{I}_{\nu~J}dx^{\nu}$ be a one-form connection with values in the Lorentz group $SO(3,1)$ and $$B_{J}^{I}=B^{I}_{\mu\nu~J}dx^{\mu}\wedge dx^{\nu}$$ a two-form with values in the Lie algebra $so(3,1)$, both defined over a four-dimensional manifold $M$. If we consider that the indices $i,j,k...$ are three-dimensional indices, let's consider the functional:
\begin{equation}S:=\int_{\sigma}\epsilon^{ijk}\omega_{AC,j}(\vec{z},t)\omega_{~~B,k}^{C}(\vec{z},t)B_{0i}^{AB}(\vec{z},t)d^3z,\end{equation}
where $\epsilon^{ijk}:=\epsilon^{0ijk}$ and $\sigma$ is a three-dimensional slice of a four-dimensional manifold $M$.
I'm having problems calculating the functional derivative $\dfrac{\delta(S)}{\delta\omega^{EF}_{k}(\vec{x},t)}$. My problems come from the indices of the $\omega$ and from the product of two omegas in $S$
I can write $S$ as:
$$S:=\int_{\sigma}\epsilon^{ijk}\omega_{AE,j}(\vec{z},t)\omega_{k}^{EF}(\vec{z},t)B_{0i~~F}^{A}(\vec{z},t)d^3z,$$
and calculate the functional derivate using the definition
$$\dfrac{\delta(S)}{\delta\omega^{EF}_{k}(\vec{x},t)}=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\dfrac{1}{\epsilon}[S(\omega^{EF}_{k}(\vec{x},t)+\epsilon\delta^{3}(\vec{x},\vec{z}))-S(\omega^{EF}_{k}(\vec{x},t))],$$
however this will only affect the term $\omega_{k}^{EF}(\vec{z},t)$ and not $\omega_{AE,j}(\vec{z},t)$. The result is
$$\dfrac{\delta(S)}{\delta\omega^{EF}_{k}(\vec{x},t)}=\epsilon^{ijk}\omega_{AE,j}(\vec{x},t)B_{0i~~F}^{A}(\vec{x},t).$$
I'm not sure if this is correct or not.
It is also possible to write $S$ as:
$$S:=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\int_{\sigma}\epsilon^{ijk}\omega_{AE,j}(\vec{z},t)\omega_{k}^{EF}(\vec{z},t)B_{0i~~F}^{A}(\vec{z},t)d^3z-\int_{\sigma}\epsilon^{ijk}\omega_{~k}^{EF}(\vec{z},t)\omega_{~~F,j}^{G}(\vec{z},t)B_{0i~~EG}(\vec{z},t)d^3z\right),$$
and calculate
$$\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\dfrac{1}{\epsilon}[S(\omega^{EF}_{k}(\vec{x},t)+\epsilon\delta^{3}(\vec{x},\vec{z}))-S(\omega^{EF}_{k}(\vec{x},t))]$$
for each factor, but I'm still not sure if this would be correct of not.
I think the result would be something similar to apply Leibnitz rule, but I have problems dealing with the indices of $\omega$.

So the general idea with a functional derivative is that it produces Dirac deltas with respect to all the variables and Kronecker deltas with respect to all indices. In the case of the indices, they have to be in the same position (either raised or lowered). Generically, we can write this as
$$ \frac{\delta f_{ab}(x)}{\delta f_{cd}(y)}=\delta(x-y)\delta^c_a\delta^d_b . $$
So, what does one do when the quantity on which it must operate does not have the indices in the right places? You introduce Kronecker deltas (or whatever else is used to raise or lower the indices) to express the quantity in terms of the field with the indices in their correct places. Then you can apply the functional derivative without any problem. Afterward you can contract indices and integrate over variables to simplify the result.

Yeah, well... that's exatly what I did to calculate the expression I wrote before the sentence " I'm nor sure if this is correct or not". However, I don't know what to do with the product. Is my result presented correct or not?. I don't know.

Simplify the expression and evaluate the limit and you'll end up with the $\delta$-function. It is not the idea of this website to just check people's expressions for mistakes.

I perfectly know that "It is not the idea of this website to just check people's expressions for mistakes.". You do not need to remind me that. Thank you. And no, there is no way to simplify the expression.
